# If I give an answer is it not the askers responsibility to respond to it?

Tags: discussion, support

I gave two answers ([1st ans](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/what-does-space-between-spaces-mean/5827#5827) and [2nd ans](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1923/in-battleship-why-do-the-aliens-see-things-as-green-or-red/8069#8069)) to two questions. But the askers did not response to it. Neither did they commented on it nor accepted it in both the cases. I answered them as I thought I could share my own view or I could give more references.

Somedays ago I was notified by a diamond moderator of SO, that if an answer has been posted to my question in SO, I should respond to it either by commenting on it or accepting it or come up with a good answer on my own that may be an ideal answer for my question. The moderator there was informed about me not responding to answers to my questions, because the answerers flagged my questions stating the aforesaid fact.

The same thing I think is applicable here. As the askers did not respond to my answers in anyway, they should be notified about the problem. I am looking forward to the moderators about taking necessary steps.

Comment: Such is the internet, people come, people go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ideally every question on Stackexchange (including mind Movies & TV) should be an engagement between the person asking the question and the answerers, and hopefully an accepted answer.

This is the ideal, but it does not happen on every question on SE, and appears less likely to happen on the 'soft' SE sites like Movies & TV where there is not always a correct/incorrect answer - but shades of interpretation.  The practice of accepting an answer is more rigorously followed on sites like Stackoverflow - but even here it is not enforced.

I am not sure what measures you are expecting the moderators of this site to take on questions that are perfectly well asked, on topic questions - the only issue is that the OP is not engaging with you with comments, or accepting one of the answers. You suggest that one of your questions was flagged as having an issue - this is a very different situation where another user has judged your post (question or answer) has got a specific issue, and the moderator can review and help resolve the issue or close the question / delete the answer.

Unfortunately for you (and me - I have a large number of answers on such questions) there is nothing that I can or will do about this, other than encourage everyone to follow the advice of the other moderator - follow up on your question with comments and accept any answer that you think is good enough.

Please let me know if you think there is another course of action I can take.

Comment: I am just asking you to send a private message to the askers to respond to the answers on their questions by commenting, up-voting or accepting it(not necessarily). But they at least should comment why they think the answer cannot be accepted or if further discussion is needed.

Comment: Private messages are for serious issues, spam, abuse, repeatedly low quality posts - not for not commenting or accepting answers.  Realistically this is not going to happen.

Comment: Like the moderator posed to me in private message `The problem is that you aren't giving any additional reputation to those users who took the time to give you free help.` I only ask at least comments.

Comment: I agree - it is unfortunate - and we encourage people to comment, vote and accept good answers.... but I am not going to privately message everyone that does not do so.

Comment: @Mistu4u.  Sometimes when asking a question you don't always get an answer that is good enough to accept.  Your question from Nov 20 on Christian Bale has one ok-ish answer - perhaps you are just waiting for a better answer.  You have not commented or accepted this answer. On this basis, are you suggesting that I privately message you about this?  You are expecting rather too much intervention from moderators in my opinion - it would be very intrusive and counter productive to do so.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting your point!

Comment: What is "soft" site by the way?

Comment: @Mistu4u - a soft site is one like this or sci-fi, the subject is a 'softer' subject, more subjective - when compared to a more correct/inccorrect 'hard' subject like programming.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with your concern because there are no serious issues in both cases. I mean both the askers have good acceptance rates. So moderator attention is not needed.

Forcing a user to accept an answer is a bad method. I mean both of your answers are not a straight answer's. So we should leave it to the askers whether they want to accept it or not. Take the case of my own [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/in-toy-story-why-is-buzz-the-only-toy-that-does-not-believe-he-is-a-toy/4385#4385). Where community liked it but the asker didn't accept or comment on it. Even he didn't came back to this site again.

If your answer is good then it will surely get appreciation through up-votes. Moderators have other serious issues to handle, so wait for user to respond.

Comment: I am already convinced by @iandotkelly s answer. Actually I got message from another moderator previously, so I thought...

Comment: Hi @Mistu4u.  I don't know exactly what the communication was from the other mod - but when you first joined the site, you had a closed and self-deleted question and then a down-voted and close vote attracting question.  Sounds like the mod was just trying to be helpful to a new user.  Extending that to messaging everyone that does not comment or accept is just a bit to far and likely to put people off the site, never mind being a lot of work for volunteer moderators.

Comment: @Mistu4u - thank you for the question by the way - just because I disagree with you does not make your suggestion any less valid or worthy of discussion.

Comment: Thank you @iandotkelly